# Node js microseervices with aws cognito using amplify best practice

Tags: node.js, angular, microservices, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Im working on a node js api that I have divided into few small apis(microservices) that communicate with each other using request and response, and Im using angular for the front end, now I want to secure my apis using cognito and aws amplify, so im confused where should I place the aws amplify code in my project? should I put in the front end or should I have a separate node js api to handle the security? And if there is a better approach can you suggest it please, im new to Node and angular, im a java developer, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few points to consider. You did not give details about how your services communicate, I'm assuming HTTP here.

Considering you want to protect your APIs, putting security in the frontend leaves your API vulnerable to anyone not using your frontend. It would thus make sense in general, to have a common gateway/security backend service, which guards your API services.

It could be something like

`Frontend <-> Gateway <-> Microservices`

instead of

`Frontend <-> Microservices`

This would at the same time give you the opportunity to add more complex orchestration of your service architecture at a later point, without adjusting the frontend.

Now, regarding authentication, [passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/) is providing you with a really easy to use interface to add authentication to incoming requests. It supports a variety of authentication methods, including, but limited to OpenID connect (which in turn works with AWS / cognito).
Together with [express.js](https://expressjs.com/) you should be able to pull off a simple routing/security service with few lines of code, with options to extend it with more features/security stuff as needed (e.g. you might want to add session handling at some point, or more security related stuff like XSS protection and the like. There are middlewares for `express` which cover those topics).

[edit] Some more sidenotes regarding security. It might be worth looking at [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) in general, and, as a more concrete point to start from, [OWASP's ASVS project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Application_Security_Verification_Standard_Project), which is providing you with a set of guidelines you might/should follow regarding application security when developing web applications. There is a ton of cheat sheets which provides guides/best practices for common topics like session handling, cookie handling, authentication and other security related topics.

Comment: I understand all of that mate thanks for the nice answer, I have done a POC using aws serverless api, here is what I have in my serverless.yml: functions:
  create:
    handler: create.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: orders
          method: post
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam ,  so will that be secured? and if not is there any framework that can handle security for the application with less configurations to write?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with AWS/the serverless api, so I cannot help here.

Comment: basically now when i try to access any of my api endpoints it will return authentication tolen missing, so is that secure enough? Despite being a serverless, im just using serverless for the fast deplyment and testing, ill start using ec2 insted

Comment: If you want to know if your application *is secure*, I think no one here will be able to give you a reasonable answer, or provide you with a safe "secure"-certification. To make something "secure" is not a simple task like adding a flag or option here and there, it needs a proper overall application concept/architecture, and considerations in all parts of the implementation.
If you want to verify your application and assure that you don't have obvious security flaws, I suggest you do some penetration testa after implementation. See OWASP for pentest guides / tools / howtos.

Comment: To add to this, OWASP ASVS already provides a categorization into 3 levels, where level 1 provides the least security, but is viable for *most* "normal" applications, and could/should be used as a rough guildeline for what needs/should be considered when implementing applications. You didn't give too much information, but in the end a) it depends on the exposure (internet/LAN) of your app b) contents/audience (high risk/low risk) and also the aws setup might already cover parts of the security considerations for you.